# Determine variable value using an optimised if else expression

Tags: java

i want to implement this:

if code1.equals("01") ==> return mt1

else if code1.equals("02") ==> return mt2

else if code1.equals("03") ==> return mt3

How to do it using using a similar expression :

```
String ammount = code1.equals("01") ? mt1 : other expressions ...
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered using a collection instead of three separate variables? What have you *tried* in terms of using the conditional operator?

Comment: @AmiraGL, why not use a method to return the desired value for code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a ternary operator for this. It will be completely incomprehensible.

Readability tumps optimisation, and in this case you are only optimising the number of lines, which is rarely a good idea.

Consider a `switch`:

```
switch(code1) {
    case "01": return mt1;
    case "02": return mt2;
    case "03": return mt3;
    default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown myThing");
}
```

You could also set up a `Map<String, MyThing>` somewhere in the class, if `mtX` is constant:

```
final Map<String, MyThing> myThingLookup = new HashMap<>();
myThingLookup.put("01", mt1);
myThingLookup.put("02", mt2);
myThingLookup.put("03", mt3);
```

Then in your code simply do something like:

```
final MyThing myThing = myThingLookup.get(code1);
if(myThing == null)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown myThing");
return myThing;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have at the bottom is typically used for true false comparisons.

if for some reason you do not want to use a lot of if/else if/else statements you could use a switch. Please be aware that unless you have a TON of statements, if statements are still fastest.

```
switch(code1){
   case("01"):
       return mt1;
   case("02"):
       return mt2;
   .
   .
   .
}
```

etc.

Comment: Remove the `break` statements - they're unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

The ugly way:

```
return code1.equals("01") ? mt1 : ( code1.equals("02") ? mt2 : ( code1.equals("03") ? mt3 : null))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:
 `String ammount = code1.equals("01") ? mt1 : code1.equals("02") ? mt2 : mt3`

It reads: if code1.equals("01"), the value is mt1. If not, if it equals "02", it's mt2. Otherwise, mt3.

Answer (score 0):

You may possibly try using a method:

```
public MyType findMyType(String code)
{
    if("01".equals(code)) return mt1;
    if("02".equals(code)) return mt2;
    if("03".equals(code)) return mt3;
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
```